# Get sum of nested JSON

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this JSON data where "logs" is called as another serializer.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "logs": [
        {
            "work_hours": 7,
            "user": "admin"
        },
        {
            "work_hours": 8,
            "user": "admin"
        },
        {
            "work_hours": 6,
            "user": "admin"
        },
        {
            "work_hours": 4,
            "user": "admin"
        },
        {
            "work_hours": 5,
            "user": "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to get the total work_hours from logs? Tried the annotate(Sum) but I can only get the Sum of logs.id as default

Here is my `serializer.py`

```
class UserLogsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model=UserLogs
        fields=['work_hours','user']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    logs = UserLogsSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields='__all__'
```

Comment: Can you show the UserLogs models please

Comment: Sorry, please can you update as per my comment above? I would like to complete this answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will wager a guess and say you want something like

```
 User.objects.aggregate(Sum('logs__work_hours'))
```

OR

```
User.objects.aggregate(hours_worked=Sum('logs__work_hours'))
```

And then it will be accessible on all objects in the queryset as if it was a declared property or field.

Comment: No problems, glad to assist :)